# PHP create table with POST information, loop through variables that are populated

Tags: php, html, loops, post, html-table

I have the following post variables:

```
$line_1_09
$line_1_12
$line_1_15
$line_1_18
$line_1_21
$line_2_09
$line_2_12
$line_2_15
$line_2_18
$line_2_21
$line_3_09
$line_3_12
$line_3_15
$line_3_18
$line_3_21
```

I know from my previous form that of the 15 inputs(posts) 12 are populated. the 12 is stored in variable $populatedrows.

I then want to create a table on my new page

```
<table>
<?php for ($i=1; $i<=$populatedrows; $i++)
  {
?>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <input type="text" value="//first post with information//">
       </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

so in this example, if `$line_1_09` and `$line_1_12` are empty, the first table row input must then be `$line_1_15`

and so it will continue 'looping' through the next available / populated post variables until the table is equal to `$populatedrows`. this will be equal to the number of post variables that contain data.

Strange situation for me so not really sure how to go about it.

Comment: where are the variables $line_x_y stored? In an array or what?

Comment: they are simply Post values. so $line_x_y=$_POST['line_x_y']. I can rename these variables to anything. not sure on how to use an array? Thanks Sankalp

Comment: then what is $populatedrows?

Comment: that is a value from the previous form that specifies how many of the post inputs were populated. this variable can be ignored if required but thought it would be useful to use in the for loop. if the posts can be an array somehow, then that can be used to control the for loop??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you just want to create input for each not empty $_POST variable:

```
    <?php
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) //$key is e.g 'line_1_20'
    {
        // substr($key, 0, 5) == 'line_' checks if the $key starts with 'line_'
        if((substr($key, 0, 5) == 'line_') && !empty($value))
        {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $value ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

If you want less then all populated $_POST:

```
    <?php
    $count = 0; //count rendered fields
    foreach($_POST as $value)
    {
        if(!empty($value))
        {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $value ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        $count++; //increase counter
        }

        if($count == $populatedrows) //if the coutner hits the requested amount break the loop
            break;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Great stuff. so PHP posts, by default are stored in an array named $_POST and you can loop through it from there? awesome. now can you loop through post array values starting with `line_` so all other post information is ignored?

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate your variable names, bit ugly :-) http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Just do each one and test isset(), if so output it.

e.g.
you can nest a couple of for loops to generate the indexes (1,2,3) and (9, 12, 15, 18, 21). then get your variables

```
$var_name = '$line_' . $i . '_' . $j;
echo ${$var_name};
```

You'll have to pad in the leading zero on $j for 9 -> 09

You may consider iterating through the post data, but your code then becomes broken if you change the amount or sequence of the post data being sent to the page.

If the data is not in the correct order for your table, put it into an array and then do the table write after.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean. isset is easy enough, but how do I work out which variable to look at inside my for loop? Thanks Al.

Comment: great theory, I will give it a try definitely. Thanks Al. how or what is `pad` in the zero? how do you do that?

Comment: well easier to rename your post with $line_1_09 -> $line_1_9 :-) But if you need to keep the names then you will need to test that the second variable is 2 characters long, and if not add a leading 0 to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <table>
    <?php for ($i=1; $i<=$populatedrows; $i++)
      {
       if(isset($_POST[$i])) {
    ?>
         <tr>
           <td>
             <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST[$i] ?>">
           </td>
        </tr>
    <?php }
} ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, if the post is empty, then the table will have a blank row? how do I get around that?

Comment: Thanks Sankalp, understand the principle. let me give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try?

```
<table>
<?php for ($i=1; $i<=$populatedrows; $i++) : 
if (!empty($populatedrows)) continue;
?>
  <tr>
     <td>
       <input type="text" value="//first post with information//">
     </td>
  </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Daanvn, interesting code snippet. your theory here is to loop through each post and if not empty continue. what happens if it is empty? does it skip that instance of $I or end the entire loop? Thanks,

Comment: @Smudger if its is empty it will skip and continue with the next one.